# Python : Same file output different binary

Tags: python, binary, pyramid

I'm trying to render a special file ( .pkpass to be exact ) via a backend call made to a controller. I think i got this part right, i just want my controller to serve me a specific file, here's the code

```
@view_config(name='pkpass', request_method='GET')
def post_mobile(request):
  print('hitting')
  pkppass = open('/Users/jamthor/Downloads/good.pkpass','rb')
  pkread = pkppass.read()

  try :
   res = Response(body=pkread, content_type = 'file/vnd.apple.pkpass;base64')
   res.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="test.pkpass"'
 except Exception as e :
   print(e)
 finally:
  pkppass.close()  

 return res
```

The problem isn't in serving the file ; after downloading the file via a XMLHttpRequest, it can't be opened. My first thought were about a corrupted binary, so i opened the original file ( named good.pkpass, which works ) into my editor and tried to compare with the one i got served from my application ( named test.pkpass )

The problem is they look pretty much the same ( it's binary though ), but i can spot few differences ( eventhough they are subtle, in binary it means a completely different things )

i've attached 2 screenshots below, you can see a missing `&` character from left to right where my cursor is ( thus proving there actually is a difference )

My question is : Why does the same file gives me different binary ? and consequently, why does the original file can be opened just fine while the other wont ?

[image]

Comment: I noticed that you used `'rb'` as a parameter in `open()`, where **b** stands for binary.. have you tried leaving that as simply `'r'`?

Comment: @burnzZ i will not send the binary if i omit the `b`

Comment: Does it work with `content_type='application/octet-stream'`?

Comment: Two questions 1) How do you serve the file - how is your web server configuration. Explain *all* layers that touch the HTTP request, like Apache, Nginx, etc. 2) How do you download the file - have you confirmed the results with command line tools like *curl* or *wget*